# How to return values from a LINQ query and display them in a table using C#, ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have written a linq query from which I would like to obtain the values from that query and display the results in a table. I keep getting an error that reads as shown below

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType5`6[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[App.Web.marketingdbclients_invalidEmails]'

When I scaffolded the view from the controller I picked one of my tables as the model and I don't think that is the right way to do it. What is the right type of model to pick if I want to display results from a linq query and or stored procedure because I also have a stored procedure that does the same thing as the linq query so perhaps I could use the sp as an alternative

```
public class InvalidEmailsController : Controller
{
    private MarketingDBEntitiesModel db = new MarketingDBEntitiesModel();

    public ActionResult InvalidEmails(int UploadId)
    {
        //var emails = db.sp_marketing_getInvalidEmailsByUploadId(UploadId);

        var emailTable = (from mie in db.marketingdbclients_invalidEmails
                          join mdt in db.marketingdbclients_dataTable on mie.ClientId equals mdt.ClientId
                          where mdt.UploadId == 88 
                          select new  
                                 {
                                      mie.ClientId,  mie.Email1, mie.Email2, 
                                      mie.Email3, mie.Email4, mie.DateStamp
                                 });

        return View(emailTable);              
    }
}
```

This is my view which is bound to a a table as model (which I think is the wrong method)

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Web.marketingdbclients_invalidEmails>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email1)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email2)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email3)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email4)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateStamp)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email3)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email4)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateStamp)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.invalidEmailId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.invalidEmailId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.invalidEmailId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: "select mie" instead of "select new  {mie.ClientId,  mie.Email1, mie.Email2, mie.Email3, 
           mie.Email4, mie.DateStamp}" will work

Comment: That's because "new {...}" returns AnonymousType, not App.Web.marketingdbclients_invalidEmails. Also you can't (at least with EF 6) write something like "select new App.Web.marketingdbclients_invalidEmails { ClientId = mie.ClientId... }", you should create DTO class for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass an anonymous type to 'App.Web.marketingdbclients_invalidEmails' so that's the way it produces an error.

You need to create a new View Model with required properties that you want to project from LINQ and show in your view.

```
public class marketingdbclients_invalidEmailsVM
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Email1 { get; set; }
    public string Email2 { get; set; }
    public string Email3 { get; set; }
    public string Email4 { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }
}
```

Now use this view model for your LINQ

```
public ActionResult InvalidEmails(int UploadId)
{
        //var emails = db.sp_marketing_getInvalidEmailsByUploadId(UploadId);

        var emailTable = (from mie in db.marketingdbclients_invalidEmails
                          join mdt in db.marketingdbclients_dataTable on mie.ClientId equals mdt.ClientId
                          where mdt.UploadId == 88
                          select new marketingdbclients_invalidEmailsVM
                          {
                              ClientId = mie.ClientId,
                              Email1=mie.Email1,
                              Email2=mie.Email2,
                              Email3=mie.Email3,
                              Email4=mie.Email4,
                              DateStamp=mie.DateStamp
                          });

        return View(emailTable);
    }
```

And bind your model using a new created View Model.

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Web.marketingdbclients_invalidEmailsVM>
```

Hopefully, it will resolve your problem.

Comment: thanks it works like a charm. Could I use the same method if I want to use a stored procedure? I am asking because I read somewhere that stored procedures are faster

Comment: Yes, But store procedures are a little bit complicated. I think you don't need to implement store procedures for these little tasks untill you have a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model in view:

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Web.marketingdbclients_invalidEmails>
```

You must return the same type from the controller action.
Change this:

```
... select new  {...});
```

to this:

```
... select new App.Web.marketingdbclients_invalidEmails {...}).ToList();
```

and model to:

```
@model List<App.Web.marketingdbclients_invalidEmails>
```

Good luck